# Bash conditions always evaluate true in script

Tags: bash, function, conditional-statements

I have a condition which seems to always be evaluated as true.

```
#!/bin/bash

checkFolder() {
    echo "[checkFolder]"
    echo "check $1"
    [ -n "$1" ] && [ -d "$1" ] && return 0
    echo "[/checkFolder]"
    return 1
}

rootFolder=$1

echo "check $rootFolder"
checkFolder "$rootFolder"
echo "res: $res"   # !! <--- I omitted this test line, as I thought it was irrelevant. 
echo "ret: $?"
```

When I execute my script, any path will give me a return value of 0. Which means that any string I provide seems to be seen as non-empty as well as an existing directory. I tried with:

```
./myScript.sh "."
./myScript.sh ""
./myScript.sh "wqert"
```

I will aways get a return value of 0. How comes? 
If I run this command in my terminal:

```
param=""
[ -n "$param" ] && [ -d "$param" ] && echo ok
# returns nothing

param="hello"
[ -n "$param" ] && [ -d "$param" ] && echo ok
# returns nothing

param="/home"
[ -n "$param" ] && [ -d "$param" ] && echo ok
# returns "ok"
```

Why doesn't it work in my script?

Comment: Do you believe that setting a variable named `param` will result in `$1` taking on that value?

Comment: The script, `./myScript.sh`, works fine for me.

Comment: For the command in the termianl, that was a mistake, I just corrected it. However, in my script function `checkFolder`, `$1` does take the argument passed as a value. So my problem remains.

Comment: @kaligne So, now you have your answer: that `echo` line is relevant.  It sets an exit code and the final `echo "ret: $?"` returns the exit code of the preceding `echo` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I realised the problem came from a line I omitted, as I thought it was irrelevant here. I added it in my post: `echo "res: $res"`, which comes before my call to `$?`. So now I guess an `echo` returns the value `0` here? Is there an other way for me to retrieve the return value aside from the variable `$?` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$?` is the exit code of the last executed command. In your case, the last executed command is `echo`, not `checkFolder`.

If you want to execute other commands between running a command and checking its status, assign it to a variable with `myvar=$?`

Answer (score 1):

What the command `return` changes is the "exit code" of the function.
Add this:

```
 checkFolder "$rootFolder"
 echo "the exit code was $?"
```

And see the effect of your `return 0` and `return 1`.